# Getting data from external API and posting it back to MVC action controller to insert into sql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

As I have never done this before I need some help.
So I need to get data from an external website API then send some of the collected data to an MVC controller action to insert them into a SQL database.
Does anyone know a good reference or idea on how to do that?
I have googled it for while and I was able to get the data from the website using Ajax calls, now I need to sort of try to save some of the collected data into a list of some form to post it back to the controller to save into sql database table.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers

Comment: Please show some research effort. This is not a website to outsource and get your work done.

Comment: I have been researching and working on this projects for few months, I didn't reach out until i couldn't find the answer online in my research i found the following:
https://blog.bitscry.com/2017/10/03/posting-data-to-an-mvc-controller-with-jquery/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9Uwrmgu-oE
https://dev.to/bjhaid_93/beginners-guide-to-fetching-data-with-ajax-fetch-api--asyncawait-3m1l
These are some i kept track off but there are many more. As i couldn't figure it out i reached to this website, if for some reason this is not the website to reach out for help happy to delete my account.

Comment: We are a community of people who like to help each other. Please don't take my comment in a rude manner. It just makes others lives easier to understand what exactly is the trouble you are going through so that they can get a clear picture of how they can help you. You can ask a new question with details and I am sure someone will help you out.

Comment: No problem i will try to ask another question.